# Why >>24 causes -Wconversion but >>23 doesn't?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char f(uint32_t RGBA)
{
  return (RGBA>>24) & 0xFF;
}
```

When compiled with `-Wconversion` it causes "warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]". If I lower the shift value to 23 or less the warning disappears.

I've looked through the C99 standard and I don't understand what happens here. If I remove the `&` operator then the warning is always emitted and that is probably good, as the result of the expression (after integer promotions) is larger than `unsigned char`. My only idea is that the warning is omitted for smaller shifts only because gcc is smart and sees that the result is 8-bit anyway, as the standard doesn't make this a special case. Am I right here?

And why does the shift value matter? Is that a GCC bug? Clang seems to not produce the warning for any shift values.

I'm using GCC 5.3.1 on a 64-bit Linux system.

Comment: IMO: errant warning, a bug.  It complains about `return (RGBA>>24) & 0xFF`, but not `return (RGBA>>24) & 0xFE`

Comment: The above code compiles clean on gcc 4.8.3.

Comment: @dbush with `-Wconversion`, I assume?

Comment: Correction:  with -Wconversion gcc 4.8.3 **does** show the same problem.  It does *not* appear in gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: Looks related to [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752) ... [this one looks closer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67764).

Comment: It's just plain buggy. Shifting an unsigned 32 bit value to the right by 24 guarantees a result in the range 0 to 255; the AND-ing with 255 is unnecessary.  If the AND is present, the shift is irrelevant: the uint32_t value that is being converted to unsigned char is the AND-ed one, which is in the range 0 to 255.    Without the AND, we would expect the smaller shift to produce a warning; shifting right 23 bits caps the result to 511, so it potentially doesn't fit.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour please make it an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Shafik Yaghmour, this appears to be a bug in GCC:

[GCC Bug 40752: -Wconversion generates false warnings for operands not larger than target type](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752)

It appears to have been present since version 4.4.0, first reported on 2009-07-14, and has 5 duplicates.  Based on the comments in the bug report, there seems to be some debate on how to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

At least with `gcc` `5.4`, `6.x` and `7.x` this issue has a simple work-around using a cast:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char f(uint32_t RGBA)
{
  return (unsigned char) ((RGBA>>24) & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: @wRAR I know that. I just wanted to offer a workaround. I should have added a comment, probably.